# Upgrading from VB6 to VB.net with mdb database connection

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I wrote a working VB6 application that I now need to upgrade to VB.net.
I've used Visual Studio 2008 to import (& upgrade) the original VB6 .vbp , I have an issue with connection to a local .mdb database

I'm totally confused regarding the easiest method for me to use in VS2008, nothing seems to work for me .

If you look at the methods I used in VB6, can similar methods be used in VS2008, if not what is the easiest upgrade procedure.

Presently I'm getting upgrade errors of "Property 'fields' is Readonly" each line of code that tried to write to the database record (rsd!Connection = Text7.Text) and

errors of "Too many arguments to 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Fields() As DAO.Fields"
when I try to read (Text3(0).Text = rs!Name)

Snippets of my original VB6 code are here

```
Public daoDB36 As Database
Public rs, rsc, rsd, rse As DAO.Recordset


Set daoDB36 = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("c:\program files\2807\2807.mdb")

Set rs = daoDB36.OpenRecordset("System Overview", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsc = daoDB36.OpenRecordset("Controllers", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsd = daoDB36.OpenRecordset("References", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rse = daoDB36.OpenRecordset("PWRUnits", dbOpenDynaset)

rse.MoveFirst
For x = 1 To rse.RecordCount

refelectype(x) = rse.Fields(1)
oprat(x) = rse.Fields(2)
contref(x) = rse.Fields(3)
prottrip(x) = rse.Fields(4)
lcd(x) = rse.Fields(5)
dispscroll(x) = rse.Fields(6)
ramp(x) = rse.Fields(7)
For y = 1 To 6
    accesscd(x, y) = rse.Fields(7 + y)
Next y
For y = 1 To 6
    configcd(x, y) = rse.Fields(13 + y)
Next y
underprot(x) = rse.Fields(20)
overprot(x) = rse.Fields(21)
For y = 1 To 7
    fl(x, y) = rse.Fields(21 + y)
Next y

For y = 1 To 4
    myip(x, y) = rse.Fields(28 + y)
Next y

For y = 0 To 8
    fl(x, y + 8) = rse.Fields(33 + y)
Next y

anodes(x) = rse.Fields(42)
shuntVV(x) = rse.Fields(43)
shuntA(x) = rse.Fields(44)
norefs(x) = rse.Fields(45)
varg(x) = rse.Fields(46)
modde(x) = rse.Fields(47)
demandd(x) = rse.Fields(48)
MonitorPU(x) = rse.Fields(49)
rse.MoveNext
```

Next x

Comment: I have a blog post that shows the common way to access data in VB.NET (it also shows the same code in C#). You can find it here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-sql-statement/

Comment: you'd be better off rewriting it in .NET to take advantage of 21st Century technologies - a class for instance rather than breaking an item up into 20+ individual arrays

Comment: @Plutonix arrays? VB6 has classes.